# Vector representation of documents for text classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word-embeddings, doc2vec

I'm looking for proper method of document embeddings. I know that **doc2vec** will give me the vector representations for given corpus, but how do I embed new documents? I need to train neural network that will classify text, but I have no idea how new documents should be embedded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Documents embeddings are constructions from (sub)word embeddings. Nowadays, you should always start from a pre-trained model. Please check [tensorflow Hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4) or [Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/encoderdecoder.html). Even without retraining, as long as your text is not too specific, the pre-trained encoder should capture enough relations.

Comment: Thank you, that is saving me!